# Dynamic Path in XQUERY

Tags: xquery

This is my xml-file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<QQ:Envelope xmlns:QQ="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <SOAP-ENV:Header>
      <RR:ABCInfo xmlns:RR="http://abc.test.de/abc/SOAP-Header/1.0">
         <RR:Version>2.2.2.2</RR:Version>
         <RR:BuildRevision>3333</RR:BuildRevision>
         <RR:BuildTimestamp>2019-01-01T00:00:00.000+02:00</RR:BuildTimestamp>
         <RR:Start>2019-01-01T10:10:10.101+02:00</RR:Start>
         <RR:End>2019-01-01T11:11:11.111+02:00</RR:End>
         <RR:Something>2.222 sek.</RR:Something>
         <RR:Anything/>
      </RR:ABCInfo>
      <work:WorkContext xmlns:work="http://test.com/">1234567890abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz</work:WorkContext>
   </SOAP-ENV:Header>
   <QQ:Body>
      <TT:testA xmlns:TT="http://abc.test.de/XYZ/2.0.1" xmlns:RR="http://abc.test.de/abc/abcdefgh/1.0">
         <TT:testB>
            <TT:testC>
               <TT:testD>                  
                  <TT:testE id="1234567" quellID="09876543">
                     <TT:data>urn:de:abc:test:whatever</TT:data>
                     <TT:changeDate>2019-02-02T02:02:02.020+02:00</TT:changeDate>
                     <TT:part1 listURI="urn:de:abc:codeliste:555" listVersionID="V12">
                        <code>555_777</code>
                        <name>Fischers Fritze</name>
                     </TT:part1>
                     <TT:piece2>Frische Fische fischen</TT:piece2>
                     <TT:begin>
                        <TT:date>20191231</TT:date>
                     </TT:begin>
                  </TT:testE>
               </TT:testD>
            </TT:testC>
         </TT:testB>
      </TT:testA>
   </QQ:Body>
</QQ:Envelope>
```

I have a XQuery, where I have to return XML. The first element in the returning XML is "result". The other elements in the returning XML should be dynamically created.

I get 2 sequences from outside, though I have made 2 fix Sequences in the following example to test it.
In Sequence No 1 I get the names for the other elements.
In Sequence No 2 I get the related path to the element names in Sequence 1.

I open the XML file an read a path (there might be several elements, though in my example is only one.
Then I want to process this result in a loop and return the dynamic elements.
If I access the path with a fix value (variable $c in the following code) I get the correct value, but then I must know the elements in Sequence 1 and the path in Sequence 2.
If I concatenate the path then I get the value from all elements.

This is my XQuery Code:

```
declare namespace TT="http://abc.test.de/XYZ/2.0.1";
declare namespace QQ="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/";

declare function local:getValue($path) as xs:string {
      if (fn:exists($path)) then
      (
          data($path)
      ) else (
          ""
      )
};

let $a := ('part1', 'piece2', 'beginDate')
let $b := ('TT:part1/name','TT:piece2', 'TT:begin/TT:date')

for $x in doc("Test.XML")/QQ:Envelope/QQ:Body/TT:testA/TT:testB/TT:testC/TT:testD/TT:testE

return <result>
      {
      for $item at $ind in $a
          let $c := local:getValue($x/TT:part1/name)
          let $d := local:getValue($x || concat("/", $b[$ind]))

          return element { $item } {$c, "  ---  ", $d}
      }
   </result>
```

Is there a possibility to access the path dynamically?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Which XQuery processor do you use? Some have dynamic evaluation features like BaseX http://docs.basex.org/wiki/XQuery_Module#xquery:eval

Comment: Technically you can do dynamic XPath evaluation from XQuery 3.1 by constructing an XSLT stylesheet containing the XPath expression, and invoking it using fn:transform(). However, the chances of this working are about the same as finding that your processor has its own, more straightforward approach to the task. The challenge is generally how to pass the context for XPath evaluation (e.g. namespaces, variables, etc)

Comment: In my test I'm using BaseX.

Comment: But in production I would embed it in a PL/SQL-Procedure in an Oracle 12c database (So no XQuery 3.1 is possible). Maybe we will change the database to Oracle 18 in a few weeks, but I think Oracle 18 only can Xquery 3.0.

Comment: As that feature is beyond the standardized XQuery language features and furthermore in the database world, at least as far as I can tell, most XQuery support on XML column types in mainly relational database systems often doesn't make any effort to implement the full W3C standard anyway, I think you need to look into the features your particular database system offers for XQuery dynamic evaluation, if that is what you really need. I am not quite sure whether you really need to use path expressions in strings.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.xqueryfunctions.com/xq/functx_dynamic-path.html could help - at least did it help ME ;)

> The functx:dynamic-path function dynamically evaluates a simple path expression. The function only supports element names and attribute names preceded by @, separated by single slashes. The names can optionally be prefixed, but they must use the same prefix that is used in the input document. It does not support predicates, other axes, or other node kinds. Note that most processors have an extension function that evaluates path expressions dynamically in a much more complete way.